# Magento 2 : Get Shipping price below min. amount

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.2, shipping-methods

I need to get a quote in Magento2 cart page shipping estimation like Magento 1.x.

How to show all the shipping methods when entering any zip code.

I'm using webkul marketplace extension for sellers shipping so I need min amount is there else I need to add an amount to the particular method, display in the frontend.

> Example shipping method 1 having min. order value $200 after it's free. Below $200 I need to add some amount.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain your question more?
You want to configure the shipping method.?

Comment: Yes I'm using webkul marketplace extension for sellers shipping so I need min amount is there else I need to add amount to the particular method

Comment: If you want to display other method then you need to do it from the admin configuration shipping method.

Comment: Yes, I need a similar method like a free ship but I need below minimum order  I need to add some price.

Comment: @venkataprasad have you solved it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use owebia shipping extension.  install from

https://marketplace.magento.com/owebia-owebia-shipping-2.html
[image]

https://en.store.owebia.com/magento2-module-advanced-shipping.html

Here's documentation for configuration.

https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc

**condition 1**:-For any zipcode,if order value $200 after it's free shiping_method1. and if value is less than $200 ( shipping_method2). 
[image]

```
{
   "shiping_method1": {
      "label": "Free shipping",
      "conditions" : {cart.price-tax+discount} > 200.00 // if value more than $200 
      "fees": 0

   }
  "shiping_method2": {
      "label": "Express Shipping",
       "conditions": "( {shiping_method1} ) && ( {cart.price-tax+discount} < 10 )",   // if value less than $200 then add any amount you want.
       "fees": 12  //some amount you need to add
```

}
    }

this is how you create multiple shipping methods with multiple conditions.

Hope it help you !  if any issue I love to Help you further..

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time. It's working but my requirement is changes

Comment: Awesome plugin. Saved my life! <3

Answer (score 0):

- First You need to disable free shipping and enable flatrate.
- After that you need to set two different rules from the shopping cart price rules.
- One Will be for free shipping over order of 100$ and another one for 5$ discount along with free shipping discount (//your conditions here).

Hope this helps.

Thanks