# Create custom shipping rate programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price, shipping, custom

I want to create custom shipping rate according to a formula which is Shipping rate = product weight + 10.00$ and add it to total grand total programmatically. I wanted to know the procedure for creating it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may check my another answer for magento 2 that's worked https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222806/magento-2-get-shipping-price-below-min-amount/222853#222853

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple shipping methods with different shipping price by using free Magento plugin i.e.MatrixRate of webshopapps.

You can download plugin from here : 
https://webshopapps.com/row/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html?___store=row

Video link for how to set up Matrix Rates shipping:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=90&v=u6MjF4oya3Y

This Magento extension is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**How to add custom shipping price when create order programatically in Magento**

**Step 1:** **Add below code in custom order create function.**

```
$shippingPrice = 20;
Mage::register('shipping_cost', $shippingPrice);
```

**Step 2: Now open file**

```
app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php
and add the code below.
```

**Find code::**

```
$method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
$method->setCost($shippingPrice);
```

**And replace with::**

```
if(Mage::registry('shipping_cost'))
{
 $method->setPrice(Mage::registry('shipping_cost'));
 $method->setCost(Mage::registry('shipping_cost'));
} else {
 $method->setPrice('0.00');
 $method->setCost('0.00');
}
```

**Step 3: Done. Clear the cache.**

```
Note: Override the file app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php in local like : app\code\local\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php ... as you know :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Owebia shipping extension which is available free of cost..  [here](https://en.store.owebia.com/magento1-module-advanced-shipping.html) and [marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/owebia-owebia-shipping-2.html) ( Don't worry about quality code as it's on marketplace)

[image: owebia extension for magento 1]

```
{
   "id_012": {
      "label": "Shipping",
      "fees": "{product.attribute.weight-tax+discount} + 10.00"
   }
}
```

worked for any formulas and conditions..

check documentation for rule [here](https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc)..